# How do I disable the required address fields in the checkout page?

Tags: 8, commerce

In Drupal 8, the Commerce Core module has a step after the customer selects checkout.

Left in the screen there is the payment information which contains a form with:

- Country
- Company
- First and last name
- Street address
- Postal code
- City

We only want:

- Country
- First and last name

I implemented `hook_form_alter()` but the form retrospection gives me no clue on which field I can adjust.

I also checked in the profile if there is any option, but I could not find them.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the address field on the *Customer* profile type.

See `admin/config/people/profiles/manage/customer/fields/profile.customer.address`

In more recent versions of Commerce this can be found under
`admin/config/people/profile-types/manage/customer/fields/profile.customer.address`

Comment: thxs, but this field is locked. I delete all customers already but fields keeps unlocked. Any suggestion?

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere, you need to run a recent Commerce version (2.7 or newer, in this case).